# Action with unknow number of parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a flexible dialog system, I have a static `IEnumerator` that type every char from a string that I pass, after finishes it will run a method:

```
public static IEnumerator Typewritter(..., Action method)
{
    //My logic...
    method();
}
```

When I call it in another class, I'm able to pass a void method normally:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
         EnemyPresentation();
    }

    void FadeEnemy()
    {
         //Logic.
    }

    void EnemyPresentation()
    {
         StartCoroutine(Dialog.Typewritter(..., FadeEnemy));
    }
}
```

My question is, I have some methods that have parameters, and I cannot pass them in the `IEnumerator` - is there a way to specify an `Action` with an unknown amount of parameters?

Examples of my other methods:

```
void ChangeBoxSize(RectTransform box, Vector2 size, float animDuration){}
void ShowBubble(Image bubble, bool isVisible){}
void EnableAttackometer(bool boolean){}
```

Tried `Action<>` with some generics configs, but they didn’t work.

Comment: The way you describe is not possible.  Each of those needs to be handled differently.  It would be helpful to show **how** you are using those functions.  Using object oriented programming would likely solve this, something like the command pattern comes to mind.  Without the details of how those functions are used, we can only guess a potential solution.  The simple example of calling `method();` does not show how you would handle a parameterized method.

Comment: @hijinxbassist They are mostly animations, `Dialog.Typewriter()` is part of my `namespace`, so I can call it from various scripts and scenes. 

I have the scripts OverworldAnimation and UIAnimation that store the animations, basically I want to run the Typewriter and after it finish, run an animation, so far I only can run no parameterized void methods, like a Move() method from other scripts that just move the transform down using DOTween.

I want a ordened method executions, I call Typewriter, when finished, itself execute a method passed as argument, in this case **Action method**.

Comment: Check out the command pattern.  You essentially encapsulate the functionality into an object, and that object has a single method `Execute` which when called handles the functionality.  Then you can pass in your Command and the command will do the work, but you can initiate it from your typewriter.

Comment: Ok, thank you, gonna check it later, again thank you! :D

Comment: For future reference: Please do not use italic formatting on all your text. The thinner, slanted text is more difficult to read. Just use plain text. Also, the <kbd> formatting is for keyboard keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, etc.), not normal words or letters. You can mark code inline by surrounding it with single backticks. I've edited to clean up the formatting in your post so that it's readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I don't know whether you'd really ever want to do this or not. Once set up, it works, and it does what you were asking (within limits). This is more an exercise in finding a solution to a question. So, with that being said, let's look at how you would implement a solution using generics.

Firstly, you would determine how many arguments you'd like as a maximum. From that number, you would create that many methods, all called the same, but with differing numbers of parameters. Like so:

```cs
public IEnumerator TypeWriter<T1> ( string text, Action<T1> a, T1 t1 )
{
    var c = StartCoroutine ( TypeWriterEnumerator ( text ) );
    yield return c;
    a?.Invoke ( t1 );
}

public IEnumerator TypeWriter<T1, T2> ( string text, Action<T1, T2> a, T1 t1, T2 t2 )
{
    var c = StartCoroutine ( TypeWriterEnumerator ( text ) );
    yield return c;
    a?.Invoke ( t1, t2 );
}

public IEnumerator TypeWriter<T1, T2, T3> ( string text, Action<T1, T2, T3> a, T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3 )
{
    var c = StartCoroutine ( TypeWriterEnumerator ( text ) );
    yield return c;
    a?.Invoke ( t1, t2, t3 );
}

private IEnumerator TypeWriterEnumerator ( string text )
{
    // Your typerwriter logic ... e.g.:
    Debug.Log ( $"Start TypeWriterEnumerator ('{text}') [{Time.time}]" );
    yield return new WaitForSeconds ( 1f );
    Debug.Log ( $"End TypeWriterEnumerator  [{Time.time}]" );
}
```

Now, to actually use this, let's look at a full code example:

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start ( )
    {
        StartCoroutine ( TypeWriter ( "Hello T3", Action3, 1, 2.0f, this.gameObject ) );
    }

    // An example of an action you want called after the type writer has finished. This one has three parameters.
    private void Action3 ( int a, float b, GameObject c )
    {
        Debug.Log ( $"-> Action3({a}, {b}, '{c.name}')" );
    }

    public IEnumerator TypeWriter<T1> ( string text, Action<T1> a, T1 t1 )
    {
        var c = StartCoroutine ( TypeWriterEnumerator ( text ) );
        yield return c;
        a?.Invoke ( t1 );
    }

    public IEnumerator TypeWriter<T1, T2> ( string text, Action<T1, T2> a, T1 t1, T2 t2 )
    {
        var c = StartCoroutine ( TypeWriterEnumerator ( text ) );
        yield return c;
        a?.Invoke ( t1, t2 );
    }

    public IEnumerator TypeWriter<T1, T2, T3> ( string text, Action<T1, T2, T3> a, T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3 )
    {
        var c = StartCoroutine ( TypeWriterEnumerator ( text ) );
        yield return c;
        a?.Invoke ( t1, t2, t3 );
    }


    private IEnumerator TypeWriterEnumerator ( string text )
    {
        // Your typerwriter logic ... e.g.:
        Debug.Log ( $"Start TypeWriterEnumerator ('{text}') [{Time.time}]" );
        yield return new WaitForSeconds ( 1f );
        Debug.Log ( $"End TypeWriterEnumerator  [{Time.time}]" );
    }
}
```

Remember the disclaimer at the beginning? I still stand by that. Now, my aversion to coroutines aside,` it's Unity, and the Unity engineers DO make use of coroutines, and expect developers to use them as well. This functionality was included specifically for situations similar to this, where you might want to chain coroutines.

Now, moving on from that, you'll notice that in many libraries, the engineers will include code very similar to this; methods with a varying number of generic parameters. You need look no further than the Unity documentation to see an example:
[image: Unity documentation]

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid those overloads to make my namespace more compact, (probably max I need is T6), unfortelly it cannot be 'null' like a optional parameter, thank you for the entire explanation! :)